# Using and multiplying variables in View Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a basic betting calculator on Xcode with Swift, and I'm stuck with how to multiply or even handle variables in the view controller. I managed to make the (very simple) app's algorithm with C++ in a command line, but I'd like to make it into an app so I can share it with my friends.

I'll show you the C++ code so you can understand what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <cmath>

double odd1;
double odd2;
double imput1;
double imput2;
double output1;
double output2;
double totalprofit;

int main() {
{
    std::cout << "Insert the smaller odds\n";
    std::cin >> odd1;
}

{
   std::cout << "Insert the larger odds\n";
   std::cin >> odd2;
}

{
    std::cout << "Insert bet for first instance\n";
    std::cin >> imput1;
}

{
    output1 = (odd1*imput1) - imput1;

    output2 = imput1;

    imput2 = output2/(odd2-1);
}
{
    std::cout << "Second bet has to be \n" << imput2 << std::endl;

}

{

    totalprofit = output1 - imput2;

    std::cout << "Total profit is: \n" << totalprofit << std::endl;

}

{return '0';
}
}
```

So I've made a basic UI with a form option, as a means of getting values from the user, and I've linked those to my view controller

```
@IBOutlet var odds1: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var odds2: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var imput1: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var imput2: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var output1: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var output2: NSFormCell!
```

I tried to just multiply variables like 
    var output1 = odds1*imput1 - imput1

but that didn't work. I also tried the same thing but declaring them each as doubles (as they'd have a decimal) but that didn't work.

I then tried to put them into a function like this

```
func output1(odds1: NSFormCell, imput1: NSFormCell) -> NSFormCell {

RETURN odds1*imput1 - imput1;

}

var output1 = imput1;

var imput2 = profit2/(odd2-1);
```

but I'm getting error messages and just looking at it I can tell i've done something stupid, but I really don't know what.

Here's the full code:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}


@IBOutlet var odds1: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var odds2: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var imput1: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var imput2: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var output1: NSFormCell!
@IBOutlet var output2: NSFormCell!

let odds1 = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(imput1)?.doubleValue;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C++ code your variables are already in numeric datatype - Double.

The value that you will be getting back form NSFormCell is String.

You will need to get the value of the String into a numeric datatype.

```
let odds1 = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(imput1.text)?.doubleValue
```

**Edit after code updated:**

The code you shared has a number of conceptual problems in it.  The best way i can help you to overcome these is to point you in the direction of an example of a basic calculator in swift.

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/calculator-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this technique, but it came up with an error message stating that 'instance member imput1 cannot be used on type viewcontroller'

Comment: can you copy all the view controller code so we can see what you are doing